# Is minibatch kmeans in scikit-learn having an incremental learning by using partial fit?

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn, k-means

I am about to use mini batch kmeans because i have a huge dataset is it right that i am using partial_fit everytime i input a dataset? i am using it let's say every 100 datasets is it learning an accumulated cluster centers or overwriting the old one? I am bit confused with partial fit

Comment: Are you sure that your process is processor limited and not I/O limited? CPU usage of 25% indicates usage for a single core. If you were maxing out a core, you would see 100% usage.

Answer (score 0):

25% means it is using just one core 25% ? So you are not even utilizing the single core at the first place.So in this case you should investigate that your process may be bound by something else such as Disk I/O and try to optimize that.

Talking of using all cores ( multi-cores) , I think in python there is nothing like 'true multi-threading' , you are limited by [GIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_interpreter_lock)(Global interpreter lock), so python cannot use multi-cores in that sense. You may be able to use multi-cores in python by rapping some external programs ( who support true multi-threading) inside python.

Also you can think of using go instad of python. [go vs python](https://lincolnloop.com/blog/concurrency-python-vs-go/)